# How can I attach a file as an option in Pony and Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, attachment, pony

I have problem in attaching a file as an option in Pony and Sinatra, how can I specify attachment options in Pony?

Answer (score 2):

You just pass a hash of filenames => contents:

```
Pony.mail(
  :to => 'recipient@example.com',
  :subject => "My Subject",
  :body => "My Body",
  :attachments => {
    'CompanyReport.xls' => country_report_data
  }
)
```

Now `country_report_data` should be a `String`, possibly with binary. If you wrote to a tempfile, you could do:

```
country_report_data = File.read('/tmp/1029102938123', :binmode => true)
```